# Is this plot of Ford circles actually a fractal?

Tags: fractals

Is this plot of [Ford circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle) actually a fractal?

[image]

Comment: It sure looks like one!

Comment: A special case of the Apollonian gasket in which two generators are replaced by straight lines. see, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_gasket